# jQuery - toggled allowed animations.. nothing works

Tags: jquery

Nothing happens when I click. If I assign the variable inside the first *if statement* the click then works.. so I guess that something with the *makou* variable is incorrect.

```
            var makou = TRUE;
            if(makou == TRUE){
                $( ".box_box" ).click(function() {
                    $( ".box" ).animate({
                        top: "+=300",
                    }, 50, function() {
                    });
                    makou = FALSE;
                });
            }
            if(makou == FALSE){
                $( ".box_box" ).mouseleave(function() {
                    $( ".box" ).animate({
                        top: "-=300",
                    }, 50, function() {
                    });
                    makou = TRUE;
                }); 
            }
```

Comment: What do you see when you debug it?

Comment: `TRUE` has to be written with small letters -> `true` . Please try it and tell us if you get further problems. I don't think this code does what you would expect

Comment: small letters worked like a charm! thanks!

Comment: `TRUE != true` and `FALSE != false`

Comment: you can simple use `if(makou)//this is true and if(!makou)//this is false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TRUE` and `FALSE` has to written with small letters as @Spokey said and your second event `mouseleave` is never set because variable `makou` is `true`. And when you click `makou` is going to be `false` but the `mouseleave` will not be set again after click.
Put your `if` condition inside the `mouseleave` event handler like this:

```
var makou = true;

if (makou) {
    $( ".box_box" ).click(function() {
        $(this).unbind('click'); // unbind click to allow it just one time

        $( ".box" ).animate({
            top: "+=300",
        }, 50, function() {
        });
        makou = false;
    });
}

$( ".box_box" ).mouseleave(function() {
    if(!makou) {
        $( ".box" ).animate({
            top: "-=300",
        }, 50, function() {
    });
    makou = true;
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5dzt1v6f/5/

Comment: Worked like a charm. The only thing is that I don't want to be able to click multiple times in a row. One click and then i have to "mouseleave" to be able to click again, works fine with the mouselave but not with the click.

Comment: Unbind your click handler after click or try something with `jQuery.one()`, I updated my solution... http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: I think that I am bad at axplaining. but i was trying to explain that I want it to be able to toggle between click and mouseleave a infinite number of times. every other time click and every other time mouseleave. sorry for the trubble! =)

Comment: Got it to work! Big thanks for the help! =)
JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5dzt1v6f/8/

Comment: Worked just as fine! =)